# AsyncLayoutInflater does not work with ImageView

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, layout-inflater, android-asynclayoutinflater

I am trying to use AsyncLayoutInflater for inflating my activity. Everything works fine, except one thing, all `ImageViews` are not rendered from the beginning. At some point I discovered, that if I replace `ImageView` with `AppCompatImageView` it works, but I don't want to do that for the whole screen, as it is quite complex. Why is it happening and is there a way to fix this issue?

```
val inflater = AsyncLayoutInflater(this)
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_some_layout, null) { view, _, _ ->
      setContentView(view)
}
```

Works

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/some_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_200"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:tint="@color/color_neutral_100"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_some_icon" />
```

Do not work

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/some_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_200"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:tint="@color/color_neutral_100"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_some_icon" />
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regular inflater of appcompat activity parses `ImageView` as `AppCompatImageView` but `AsyncLayoutInflater` doesn't do that. `ImageView` doesn't support any `app:` attributes.